# How to return a default value when no rows are returned from the select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that returns two columns, a date column, and a `count(value)` column.  When the `count(value)` column doesn't have any records, I need it to return a 0.  Currently, it just skips that date record all together.

Here is the basics of the query.

```
select convert(varchar(25), DateTime, 101) as recordDate,
       count(Value) as recordCount
from History
where Value < 700
group by convert(varchar(25), DateTime, 101)
```

Here are some results that I'm getting.

```
+------------+-------------+
| recordDate | recordCount |
+------------+-------------+
| 02/26/2014 | 143         |
| 02/27/2014 | 541         |
| 03/01/2014 | 21          |
| 03/02/2014 | 60          |
| 03/03/2014 | 113         |
+------------+-------------+
```

Notice it skips 2/28/2014.  This is because the `count(value)` column doesn't have anything to count.  How can I add the record in there that has the date of 2/28/2014, with a `recordCount` of 0?

Comment: Using code blocks (highlight the block and hit the `{}` button) make it much easier to get layouts as you want them (and for real code, they should also enable syntax highlighting too)

Comment: Thanks Damien, I haven't posted here before, and wasn't aware of the code blocks.  I'll keep that in mind for future posts.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Does your [History] table have the 20140228 date, even if with a [Value] >= 700, or does it not appear in that table? If it doesn't exist at all, you need to set a table with dates and then do a simple LEFT JOIN. If it does have it but Value>=700, then a LEFT JOIN with itself will do.

Comment: It's not a good practice to store a date as string: over time you'll get performance issues from these conversions in your query. You could try storing dates in a Date field and having an index over it and [Value] to speed up this kind of queries. Or, if the stored date-as-string lacks hours and minutes, you can simply avoid doing the conversion for you wouldn't need it and get a small perf. bonus (but do think of adding indexes).

Comment: The History table does have the 20140228 date, but all Values are over 700.  That's why the count doesnt return anything.  I'm converting the date as it is, because the actual field is the full timestamp, and I'm just needing the Date portion of it for these results.

Comment: OK, so the DateTime may have hours, minutes and seconds but - is it stored as a "date" or as a VARCHAR? If it's the former, there are better performing ways to take out hours/mins/secs from the date than converting it to a string: you may look for the famous question "How to floor a date in SQL Server?" in this same site.

Answer (score 2):

To generate rows for missing dates you can join your data to a [date dimension table](http://michaelmorley.name/how-to/create-date-dimension-table-in-sql-server)

It would look something like this:

```
select convert(varchar(25), ddt.DateField, 101) as recordDate,
       count(t.Value) as recordCount
from History h
right join dbo.DateDimensionTable ddt
    on ddt.DateField = convert(varchar(25), h.DateTime, 101)
where h.Value < 700
group by convert(varchar(25), h.DateTime, 101)
```

If your table uses the DateTime column to store dates only (meaning the time is always midnight), then you can replace this

```
right join dbo.DateDimensionTable ddt
    on ddt.DateField = convert(varchar(25), h.DateTime, 101)
```

with this

```
right join dbo.DateDimensionTable ddt
    on ddt.DateField = h.DateTime
```

Comment: This is the right answer, save I guess you meant RIGHT JOIN (or swapping places of [History] and [DateDimensionTable]) for Feb/28th to do appear in the results even if table [History] lacks data for it :)

Comment: @JoePineda: yes, you are right.  I've edited the answer.  Now a new thought: I'm guessing the OP may not want every date in the date dimension table.  It would most likely need to be filtered by date range using some value from History table (ie MIN(DateTime), Max(DateTime)) or some other arbitrary values (ie start/end dates for fiscal year, Q1, Q2, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You may use `COUNT(*)`. It will return zero if nothing was found for the column. Also you may group result set by value column if it is needed.

Comment: That won't produce a row for 2/28/2014 if it doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's needed to show values presented in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(varchar(25), DateTime, 101) as recordDate,
       CASE WHEN count(value) =0 THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(value) END  recordCount
from History
where Value < 700
group by convert(varchar(25), DateTime, 101)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either.  I even tried:  CASE WHEN count(Value) > 0 THEN COUNT(Value) ELSE 0 END as downCount

Comment: Take out the where clause and see if that WHERE clause is causing problem.

Comment: Sorry, the Where clause is kind of crucial.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a group by, it only creates a distinct list of values that exist in your records. Since 20140228 has no records, it will not show up in the group by.

Your best bet is to generate a list of values, dates in your case, and left join or apply that table against your history table.

I can't seem to copy my T-SQL in here so here's a hastebin.

http://hastebin.com/winaqutego.vbs

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be for you to have a datamart where a separate dimensional table for dates is kept with all dates you might be interested at - even if they lack amounts. DMason's answer shows the query with such a dimensional table.

To keep with the best practices you would have a fact table where you'd keep these historical data already pre-grouped at the granularity level you need (daily, in this case), so you wouldn't need a GROUP BY unless you needed a coarser granularity (weekly, monthly, yearly).

And in both your operational and datamart databases the dates would be stored as dates, not...

But then, since this is real world and you might not be able to change what somebody else made... If you: a) only care about the dates that appear in [History], and b) such dates are never stored with hours/minutes; then following query might be what you'd need:

```
SELECT MyDates.DateTime, COUNT(*)-1 AS RecordCount
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT DateTime FROM History
   ) MyDates
LEFT JOIN History H
  ON  MyDates.DateTime = H.Datetime
  AND H.Value < 700
GROUP BY MyDates.DateTime
```

Do try to add an index over DateTime and to further constrain the query with an earliest/latest date for better performance results.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a Dates table (AKA time dimension) is the right solution, but there is a simpler option:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DateTime, 101) AS RecordDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Value < 700 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RecordCount
FROM
    History
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DateTime, 101)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this still doesn't return any record for 2/28.

Comment: I'm assuming that your underlying data has records for all dates, but that none on 02/28 meet the "< 700" filter.  If that assumption is wrong, then no this approach won't work.  Fortunately you are spoiled for choice!  Incidentally, including a subset of the data you have will help people give you more focused and accurate answers in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Records TABLE (
    [RecordDate] DATETIME,
    [RecordCount] INT
)

DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '02/26/2014' -- Enter whatever date you want to start with
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '03/31/2014' -- Enter whatever date you want to stop
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    -- Insert the date into the temp table along with the count
    INSERT INTO @Records (RecordDate, RecordCount) 
    VALUES (CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @Date, 101), 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE RecordDate = @Date))

    -- Go to the next day
    @Date = DATEADD(d, 1, @Date)

    -- If we have surpassed the end date, break out of the loop
    IF (@Date > @EndDate) BREAK;
END

SELECT * FROM @Records
```

If your dates have time components, you would need to modify this to check for start and end of day in the `SELECT COUNT(*)...` query.

Comment: I'd recommend just building a table of dates in a loop, then running just one query after against `dbo.YourTable`. It'll be relatively slow as written.